# Minimalistic app getting "OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory" on deploy - why?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pytorch, python-3.7

I'm setting up a new Google App Engine with Python 3.7 runtime. However, it fails even with a very minimal setup.

The app.yaml is as simple as:

```
runtime: python37
```

The main.py is as simple as:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

And finally the requirements.txt is as simple as:

```
Flask>=1.0.2
torch==1.0.1
Flask-Compress>=1.4.0
numpy>=1.16.2
```

I expected that this setup would work when issuing `gcloud app deploy`, but istead I'm getting an error - this is the last lines of the error log on Google Cloud Build:

```
(log lines before this omitted as they're on INFO level)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 65, in <module>
File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 54, in main
File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/python/builder.py", line 114, in Build
File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/python/layer_builder.py", line 153, in BuildLayer
File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/common/single_layer_image.py", line 60, in GetCacheKey
File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/python/layer_builder.py", line 109, in GetCacheKeyRaw
File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/python/layer_builder.py", line 332, in GetCacheKeyRaw
File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/python/layer_builder.py", line 346, in _python_version
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 938, in _execute_child
self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

Why does it fail? Is it normal that it uses python 2.7 here, when it uses python 3.7 in the beginning? Cannot seem to find any documentation for this specific bug - I've tried to increase memory in the `app.yaml` file without any luck.

Comment: Python 2.7 is being used behind the scenes here to build the image for your app, it's unrelated. I'm able to reproduce this when installing the `torch` dependency, but this shouldn't be failing. I've filed an issue internally. If you can avoid installing `torch` for now, I'd recommend it.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE**

I have edited my answer to avoid confusion, as I was initially wrong.

As specified by [Dustin Ingram Apr 2 at 17:50](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55474474/minimalistic-app-getting-oserror-errno-12-cannot-allocate-memory-on-deploy/55477737?noredirect=1#comment97671585_55474474)'s comment. The issue is indeed with App Engine and not with the library.

Therefore, I have opened a [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129913216) for you to follow up there. You can mark this and comment to indicate that you where affected by this, that so you will get updates there regarding the progress.

Comment: This is not correct. The `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement will not be true on on App Engine, these lines are not necessary. Furthermore, additional dependencies that aren't imported don't contribute to memory overhead until they're imported.

Comment: The lines you mention will enable debugging locally, however that's not what I want. In regards to `torch` - you're right, it works without. The problem is that I sorely need it for my purpose. Thanks though!

Comment: @Dustin Ingram, you are right. I just pointed the documentation part where the minimal code for App Engine deploy example was provided by Google. I just made  it look by mistake that it might have caused the issue, but it is not! However the torch library is the one that has issues and is the one that causes the memory allocation error during deployment. So the answer wasn't completely wrong.

Comment: @zniwalla, you will have to contact the developers of torch library and point them that the library has issues, I see that this issue is not related to App Engine. Good luck!

Comment: The issue is indeed with App Engine and not with the `torch` library specifically, [see my comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55474474/minimalistic-app-getting-oserror-errno-12-cannot-allocate-memory-on-deploy/55477737?noredirect=1#comment97671585_55474474)

Comment: Oh, I am really sorry I didn't notice. Well in this case, yeah the torch library must be excluded for now. I have opened a [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129913216) as well, for you to follow up there. You can mark this and comment to indicate that you where affected by this, that so you will get updates there regarding the progress.